# More efficient way of storing data than PackedArray

Tags: memory

I have a compiled function `cfun` that produces a very large array of data. I learned that compiled functions automatically use PackedArrays. I just wonder whether there is a more efficient way in Mathematica to store large arrays of numerical data.

Is there somewhere a table where I can see how much memory a PackedArray consisting of numerical data with MachineSize precision should consume?

For an output array of length 10^8 `ByteCount[]` returns memory consumption of 1.6 GB on my machine. Would be great if somebody could tell me whether this is a normal value and whether there is a way to store the array in a more efficient way (since for the purpose of my program I need to store a list of length 10^9-10^10 which would correspond to 16-160 GB RAM).

Comment: Not an anwser, but could you use a stream to write the data to a file, using `Openwrite` ,`Write` etc? Or create an enourmous (~100gb) swap file, like I did today?

Comment: 10^8 elements will take up about 0.75 GB if the elements are real, or 1.5 GB if they are complex. Note that a gigabyte is 1024^3 bytes, not 1000^3.

Comment: Ruud3: My problem is that I need to do computational stuff with the data I create. I'm afraid, writing it to a file and then import it again won't be helpful here. Szabolcs: You are right, of course. Thank you for the reminder. Perhaps the meta data makes it 1.6 GB. I need to check again on this.

Comment: Maybe your data has certain redundancies or some "smoothness" that allow a (nearly) lossless compression...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: How can I check for redundancies or "smoothness"? Could you please provide me with an example?

Comment: If the data is sampled from a smooth function then you could use, e.g., splines (see `Interpolation`) in order to store the data with only few sampling points and recover it by interpolation...

Comment: What apllies to your data is hard to say without knowing its source...

Comment: Btw.: For pseudorandom data, you may use `SeedRandom` to generate the data and to retrieve it later without storing the actual pseudorandom numbers.

Comment: Ok, thank you I see your point. Unfortunately, I am afraid that using some nodes for `Interpolation` is not applicable in my case, since the data is really noise in the end. As, I need to compute moments from my data, I will tomorrow try to split it up in small pieces, then do the operations on it and finally take the average. The average itself can contain much less data points then the actual data list, so I think this should be feasible. For this purpose I might need to export and re-import that final data and then do the average.

Answer (score 6):

Real-type packed arrays are stored as a contiguous block of [double-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) values, plus a small bit of metadata.

This means that:

- If you have `n` elements, it takes `n*8` bytes
- There is no reasonable way to store data of the same precision more efficiently

An integer takes up 8 bytes on a 64-bit system or 4 byte on a 32-bit system in a packed array.  A complex number takes up 16 bytes (both the real and imaginary parts are double-precision).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. In fact, my numbers are complex, which explains why my array occupies 1.6 GB. Is your statement true for any programming language? Or do other languages have smarter ways of storing data? I am afraid, that my local memory will be the bottleneck for my computation then if there is no other reasonable way. :(

Comment: @DisplayName It is true for any language. If you use a low-level language like C, you can use single-precision numbers (~7 dgitis of precision), which take up half the space. 10^10 is almost never a reasonable size of an array.  Consider carefully if you really need to store this much data simultaneously. Maybe you can generate and process the data piece by piece.

Comment: Ok interesting, wasn't aware of this. I guess I cannot reduce the precision that easily with Mathematica? In principle, generating and processing the data piece by piece is a possibility. I have already thought about this but first wanted to know whether there is a more efficient way of storing the data. Essentially, it is stochastic data and I need to compute some quantities like moments etc. As it seems these averaged quantites seem to converge very slowly. This just as background information why I am aiming for such a large array.

Comment: @DisplayName It is not necessary to store a full list to compute its average (and all moments are averages, so the same applies).  Just do it piece by piece. Keep track of how many numbers you have already averaged.

Comment: That is true, of course. Though, I was more afraid about whether the total size of the list is sufficient to get a nice convergence of these averages. And I think there is no way to circumvent this problem. The maximum size of the data array (in one or many pieces) is limited by my computer's memory. Ok, I could buy more memory, but maybe I should also look again into the generation of the data. Perhaps using many arrays and changing the initial conditions for every one of them leads to a faster convergence of the averages. Though there should be no difference to just one array I suppose.

Comment: @DisplayName Mathematica encourages working with entire arrays. You generate the whole array, then you do operations on the whole array. In performance-oriented languages you would not do this. You would process those random numbers one by one as they are generated. I assume you are generating them and not reading from a file. This way memory is not an issue.  [Example](https://pastebin.com/TNjhxz7b)

Comment: Yes, the random numbers are generated within Mathematica itself. So far, I generate the whole array, and then operate on said array. If I get you right, you suggest doing all the operations within the `Compile` environment as shown in your example. Then I am still limited by the available memory (at some point I need to generated the numbers somehow or other), but I see that I can avoid unnecessary copies of data that might occur when doing operations on the whole array. Still, I think the idea with cutting the large array into pieces is most appropriate.

Comment: @DisplayName No. I simply said: don't generate *all* of it at once.  For this task you do not need to.  You are not limited by memory at all.